# Best folder structure for versioning with restify

Tags: node.js, versioning, restify

I'm making a Restful API, and I have the following folder structure in Nodejs with Restify:

```
.
├── controllers
│   └── example.js
├── models
├── routes
│   └── example.js
└── server.js
```

What is the best solution to handler different versions, I was thinking in two:

1) Base in folder structure

```
.
├── controllers
│   ├── v1.0
│   │   └── example.js
│   └── v2.0
│       └── example.js
├── models
├── routes
│   ├── v1.0
│   │   └── example.js
│   └── v2.0
│       └── example.js
└── server.js
```

But, with this solution, I must have all the controllers and routes duplicated, and if a controller didn't change, I must have a copy in the correct version folder

2) Have in the controller code the different version of each function and send the req version to get the correct function.

I hope you can understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest solution 2. It also recommended [here](http://restify.com/docs/home/#versioned-routes) [Restify Documentation]. One of the objectives of versioned routing is to avoid having to organize code this way.

This way, its easier to reuse some code wherever possible.